# PostgreSQL 9.3: REPLACE string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, string-function

I have a string to replace with the expected form.

**Input**: I have the following string.

```
'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L'
```

And I want to replace the above string into the following format:

```
'x.A = z.A ,
 x.B = z.B , 
 x.C = z.C , 
 x.D = z.D , 
 x.E = z.E , 
 x.F = z.F ,
 .........
 .........
 x.L = z.L'
```

**My try**:

```
SELECT 'x.'||REPLACE('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L',',',' = z.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'x.' || col || '=z.' || col
FROM (
      SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L', ',')) col
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_agg` and `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT string_agg(FORMAT('x.%s = z.%s', t,t) , ',')
FROM (SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L', ',')) AS t
     ) AS sub;
```

You can use as delimeter `E',\r\n'` to get carriage return:

```
SELECT string_agg(FORMAT('x.%s = z.%s', t,t) , E',\r\n')
FROM (SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L', ',')) AS t)
      AS sub
```

Output:

```
x.A = z.A,
x.B = z.B,
x.C = z.C,
x.D = z.D,
x.E = z.E,
x.F = z.F,
x.G = z.G,
x.H = z.H,
x.I = z.I,
x.J = z.J,
x.K = z.K,
x.L = z.L
```

Comment: @MAK I thought you want one result set not multiple. Please be more specific next time.

Comment: Okay! I apologize for that.